# Automatic Clearing of Rails Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using ActiveRecord::SessionStore to store user's sessions.

Is it possible to destroy a session when it expires using Devise Timeoutable? Unfortunately, I cannot use a cron task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expiry is "passive", in that it just depends on comparison between the system clock and something stored in the database: there's no event than you can hang a callback (or whatever) off.  If you want to delete expired sessions then by convention you should make a rake task to do so.  Normally you would then run this rake task at scheduled intervals.  So, your problem is "How to run a rake task at scheduled intervals without cron".

Googling for "scheduling tasks without cron" reveals a lot of leads.  I've never done this myself though.  Why can't you use cron?  If it's because you're on Heroku then Heroku provides its own scheduler.

Comment: Not using crone is the policy of the project. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you don't need the clearing of expired sessions to happen on a  regular basis, just every so often, you could add it to your deploy script.